# N(person)にもらいます

Tags: grammar

Hi I have a question which I am a bit unsure about from my textbook that I am learning Japanese from.

In my book it says

> Verbs like もらいます、かります and ならいます express actions from the receiving
>   side. The persons from whom you receive those actions are marked with
>   に. から is sometimes used instead of に in this sentence pattern. When you receive something from an organization like a school or a company only から is used.

So this brings me to my question, I know we can say something like

木村さんは山田さんから（に）花をもらいました.

So does this mean 銀行にお金を借りました is incorrect? we should use から here instead?

Furthermore my book says to use から when we receive something from an organization like a school or a company. Do they mean physically receiving something, such as money? what if we learn a language at a school? or receive a phone call from the school? For example:

語学校**から**英語を習います ( can we use に after 学校 here?)

Thanks for any answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's ok to mark institutes with に as long as you recognize them as an agent, rather than a place where the act of giving is done. In that sense, it doesn't make sense to me that they say you can't use に while から is available, even if there's preference in terms of frequency. So, 銀行に借りた is just fine.

That said, 語**学**学校に習う is not that natural than 語学学校で習う because people usually recognize 学校 as a place unless it's a party in contract or something.